# Transform Excel to SQL insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I am seeking for some help on ideas on how to get start on this. I have created a database for a training system in SQL Server. I have some old data that I would need to insert into the SQL Server database. The Excel is not in a "table" form. The data record are as shown below (row is employee name, column is Training Name, and Green box means yes). The database consist of employee name and the training.

[image: Old Database in Excel]

My expected outcome is automated generate result like

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES ("Name of training");
```

Comment: Please provide a more complete illustration of the target table into which you want to move the data.  It seems like you might just need to un-crosstab the data before loading it (see, e.g., https://pypi.org/project/un-xtab/).

Answer (score 0):

Create your table on SQL. Headers etc...

Go on the excel file, save the file as `.csv`  and on SQL software import the `.csv` file onto the new table you have just created.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a simple turn-key solution:

You're going to need to ensure your data is in the correct format prior to moving to SQL. Use a single row for header names, and then your values below that. If your data isn't in that format, you'll need to find a new way to structure the data, to ensure it's correct for a relational database like SQL. I suggest reading up on SQL data structure/relational databases if you're unfamiliar with SQL server.

Next step would be to convert the file to a CSV by using Excel save-as.

Lastly, you can use the SQL import wizard for a solution with a user interface to import your data. To access it, right click the database in SSMS, go to Tasks, then to Import Data. You can find more info on how the data import wizard works by searching.

Automating table generation off of existing data is quite a bit more complicated, and is best completed using a scripting language (like python) in addition to SQL, in my opinion.